# extract comments with javascript match and/or replace

Tags: javascript, regex, comments

I am trying to extract comments to use them.

So if I have

```
var a = 'foo';
// this comment should stay here

/* Description: I need to be printed in a section */
/* Usage: I need to be printed in another section 
   and I have multiple lines
*/
```

Expected result 1:

```
var a = 'foo';
// this comment should stay here
```

Expected result 2:

```
Description: I need to be printed in a section
```

Expected result 3:

```
Usage: I need to be printed in another section
and I have multiple lines
```

So what I basically want is 3 variables

```
var code = str.replace(regex to remove comments)
var description = str.match(regex to match comments with description)
var usage = str.match(regex to match comments with usage)
```

I can format the comments any way needed.

BTW. I am doing this inside a grunt script in case that's important

```
var str = grunt.file.read('myfile.filetype')
```

Here's an actual example

```
@import '../helpers/_prefix';

// MIXIN: .animation-delay
.animation-delay(@values) {
    @vendorPrefixes: -webkit-, -moz-, '';
    @prop: animation-delay;
    // http://caniuse.com/#search=animation
    .prefix();
}


/* Description: Defines the delay of an animation */


/* // Usage: 
  .animation-delay(200ms)
*/
```

I also want the `/*` and `*/`to be removed

The code block should output

```
@import '../helpers/_prefix';

// MIXIN: .animation-delay
.animation-delay(@values) {
    @vendorPrefixes: -webkit-, -moz-, '';
    @prop: animation-delay;
    // http://caniuse.com/#search=animation
    .prefix();
}
```

The last one (Usage) should either output

```
// Usage
.animation-delay(200ms)
```

or

```
.animation-delay(200ms)
```

Comment: How about nested comments?

Comment: Hm?  I don't need nested comments. I am writing a documentation for a library I wrote and want to extract the info from the files directly. So I can style the comments any way needed. I'm just really bad at regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
m = str.match(/\/\/.*/g);
var code = m ? m[0] : "";

m = str.match(/\/\*.*?Description: *([\s\S]*?)\*\//);
var description = m ? m[1] : "";

m = str.match(/\/\*.*?Usage: *([\s\S]*?)\*\//);
var usage = m ? m[1] : "";
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as intended. I updated the question with an "actual" usecase

Comment: looks better but the "code" part only returns the first comment line `// MIXIN: .animation-delay`. The other two seem to work pretty good.. I guess it would make sense to just strip all C comments and keep C# comments that are not nested in other comments. The nested comments can also be removed and replaced with other symbols if needed